# Hive - Fetching the cumulative sum with previous column value condition

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Input Table t1:

[image]

Output required:

[image]

Detailed Description: 
If the value of fg and x are "Carry" then value of z should be equal to calculated value of z for previous row + 1. Else z should be equal to 0.
As per the example, for first row we are considering previous calculated value of z as 0 and then incrementing it by 1 since both fg and x are equal to "Carry".

In second row, both fg and x are "Carry" and calculated value of previous row is 1 than incrementing it by 1 gives 2.

In third row, since fg and x both are not equal to "Carry" so z value is 0.

I have tried using SUM(), LAST_VALUE() functions etc. but nothing seems to work in this case. I am basically trying to replicate retain function of SAS in HIVE. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Ordering is done using id column.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is only provided using a column, and it is not clear what column specifies the ordering in your data.

Comment: Its the id column which is used for ordering in ascending order.

Comment: . . The `id` column is *not* an ordering column because it has duplicate values.  It does not specify the ordering of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the groups using a cumulative sum.  Then use `row_number()`.  In the following code `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering:

```
select t.*,
       (case when fg = 'Carry' and x = 'Carry'
             then row_number() over (partition by id, grp, fg, x order by ?)
             else 0
        end) as z
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when fg = 'Carry' and x = 'Carry' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by ?) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=33037e56010be733ce0e9c5166c9cece) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that this uses Postgres instead of Hive but that should not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. As per this code the value for first three rows is coming correctly but for fourth row it is coming as 4 since we are using the row number function but in actual it should come as 1 because we need to increment by 1 the previous row calculated value of z which is 0.

Comment: @Nitish . . . I made a small fix and included a db<>fiddle showing that the code works.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable and check if fg and x both are **Carry** then increase variable value else assign it to 0.

```
SELECT id, fg, x, if(fg='Carry' and x = 'Carry', @a:=@a+1, @a:=0) as z from t1, (SELECT @a:= 0) as a;
```

Comment: @Nitish Please check this.This will give you correct result on Mysql.